# Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message, when i going to update my database

Tags: php, laravel-5

guys i get this error

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

I check everything its gonna be okay, but i still meet the error. I use resource routing and i want going to update my data,,

this is my web.php

```
Route::resource('posts', 'MuseumController');
```

this is my edit.blade.php

```
 <form action="/posts" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    .
    .
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
</form>
```

and this is my update class

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'nama' => 'required',
            'lokasi' => 'required',
            'alamat' => 'required',
            'keterangan' => 'required',
        ]);

        //Edit file upload/fotonyaa
        if($request->hasFile('foto')){
            //Jipuk jeneng plus eksistensine
            $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('foto')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Jipuk nama file e
            $filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Jipuk eksistensine
            $extension = $request->file('foto')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to  storee
            $fileNameToStore = $filename. '_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //Upload the Image
            $path = $request->file('foto')->storeAs('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);
        }

        //Ini dia skrip untuk update datanya
        $museum = Museum::find($id);
        $museum->nama = $request->input('nama');
        $museum->lokasi = $request ->input('lokasi');
        $museum->alamat = $request->input('alamat');
        $museum->keterangan = $request->input('keterangan');

                                  //'success' didefinisikan dari file alert.blade.php                              
        return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Museum berhasil diubah');
    }
```

I think my questions its enough, and ill be waiting your answer, Thanks In Advance!

Comment: don't you have some kind of config file in laravel that tells the router which route can be accessed with what method?

Comment: I dont know what thats file,,

Comment: have you read this article https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing ?

Comment: its fixed bruh,, its wrong on form action,,, i change the action from "/post" to "post/{$museum -> id}",, and my problem was clear,, thank for your response!

Comment: Please consider answering your own question and marking it as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Error in the route you've defined. Its get and should change to post

change this

Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getLogin']);
to this

Route::post('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getLogin']);
action="{{ route('login') }}" # form Submit action